# How to prove the irreducibility $x^m+x^n+x+1$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $m>n>1$ be odd positive integers, show that $x^m+x^n+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I guess the proposition is true in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but have absolutely no idea about how to prove it.

Comment: You can find a proof for the more general situation here https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g16/g16.pdf

Comment: Great thanks, this article is really useful.

Comment: It's not true in $\mathbb{Z_3}[x]$ in general, for example $$x^9+x^3+x+1=(x^3+x^2+x+2)(x^3+x^2+2x+1)(x^3+x^2+2)$$